# How to use the buildroot toolchain in the next builds

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, toolchain, buildroot

My current setup is that every clean build will also compile toolchain which I don't want.

I want to use generated toolchain in the first build and copy it in other location and then configure the buildroot to use this toolchain.

I tried copying output/host folder to /opt folder and then modified the Toolchain options to use Custom toolchain.

It started throwing many errors.

What are the steps to achieve this scenario of using already build toolchain in a clean build

Comment: The Buildroot manual has a section called "Using the generated toolchain outside Buildroot" (https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_advanced_usage). "outside Buildroot" can also mean "in another Buildroot instance".

Comment: Use `ccache` to speed up the compilation.